# Hello, How can I use the solana/web3.js library to access the data returned by the command solana validators --output json?

Tags: web3.js, solana-cli

How can I use the solana/web3.js library to access the data returned by the command solana validators --output json?

Answer (score 1):

The getValidators function in the solana web3js library should return a list of validator public keys. These can then be passed in to getValidatorInfo to return the ValidatorInfo type containing more information about the validator.